# How to find the recurrence relation for probability of getting exactly n score during a play?

Tags: probability

A player tosses a coin and is to score one point for every head and 2 points for every tail turned up .He is to play on until his score reaches n or passes n .If pn is the probability of attaining exactly n score , then how to approach forming the recurrence for pn ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways in which he could have made the last toss to reach a total of $n$ -

1) His last score was $n-1$ after which he tossed a head making the score $n-1+1=n$

2) His last score was $n-2$ after which he tossed a tail making the score $n-2+2=n$

Consider the first case:

Probability of reaching exactly $n-1=p_{n-1}$ and the probability of the toss being head = $\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence the probability of the first case being true = $\frac{p_{n-1}}{2}$

Consider the second case:

Probability of reaching exactly $n-2=p_{n-2}$ and the probability of the toss being tail = $\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence the probability of the first case being true = $\frac{p_{n-2}}{2}$

Hence the probability of reaching exactly $n=$ probability of first case+ probability of second case

$$\therefore p_n = \frac{p_{n-1}}{2}+\frac{p_{n-2}}{2}$$

Comment: I couldn't get the logic clearly ,please explain a bit more

Comment: I just realized that I had interpreted the question in a wrong way. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Actually answer is given in terms of p(n-1) and p(n-2) it is p(n)=1/2(p(n-1)+p(n-2))

Comment: Actually this question is open to different forms of interpretations. Mine initial understanding of the question was true I guess.
I have edited the answer. Let me know if you have any doubts :)

Comment: I got this solution as well as I had understood previous solution , but couldn't get one thing that why was previous one wrong ?

Comment: I wish I knew. But quite frankly my mind is too cluttered right now to figure it out. I am working on it. Will let you know if I figure it out.