# Probability is given in the form of recurrence relation. How to solve and what is the form of recurrence relation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A player tosses a coin and is to score one point for every head turned up and two points for every tail. He is to play on until his score reaches or passes $n$. If $p_n$ is the chances for attaining exactly $n$, show that, $p_n=\frac 12 \left(p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}\right)$ and hence find the value of $p_n$.

Now the book I'm reading has given the solution of the problem. The first part of the solution is same as [How to find the recurrence relation for probability of getting exactly n score during a play?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1624645/587131)  this. And I have understood that. But for the 2nd part the book reads as follows:-
Let $p_n$ is of the form $p_n=A+Bx^n$, where $A, B$ are constants. Now using $p_n=\frac 12 \left(p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}\right)$ we get $A+Bx^n=\frac 12 [A+Bx^{n-1}+A+Bx^{n-2}]\implies 2x^2-x-1=0 \implies x=-\frac 12, 1$.
Since $p_n$ depends on $n$ so $x\neq 1$.So $p_n=A+B \left(-\frac 12 \right) ^n$. Then using given conditions they show that $p_n=\frac 13 [2+(-1)^n.2^{-n}]$.

But I can't understand why they assume that "$p_n$ is of the form $p_n=A+Bx^n$". Why they can consider $p_n$ in the form of this polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difference equation. Admittedly I am no expert in difference equations, but I can relate them to differential equations, which hopefully you are more familiar with.

Let $p(t)$ be some continuous (twice-differentiable) function such that $p_n = p(n)$. We customarily make the following approximations

$$\frac{dp}{dt} \approx \frac{p_n - p_{n-1}}{n-(n-1)} = p_n - p_{n-1}$$

$$\frac{d^2p}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{dp}{dt}  \approx (p_n - p_{n-1}) - (p_{n-1} - p_{n-2}) = p_n - 2p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}$$

And the given equation is $2p_n - p_{n-1} - p_{n-2} = 0$, solving the linear combination problem $2p_n - p_{n-1} - p_{n-2} = a(p_n - p_{n-1}) + b(p_n - 2p_{n-1} + p_{n-2})$ we obtain $a = 3, b = -1$ and the following related differential equation

$$\frac{d^2p}{dt^2} - 3\frac{dp}{dt} = 0 \implies p = c_1 + c_2e^{3t}$$

Our original difference equation is not quite this but quite similar. They are different because the slope of the secant line from $(t, p(t)$ to $(t+1, p(t+1))$ is a poor approximation of $p'(t)$, but the form $A + Bx^n$ is there.

A side note is that because $n$ is the parameter, $x^n$ is actually an exponential expression. $p$ is a "function" of $n$, not $x$.

Comment: I'm unable to understand how do you relate $A+Bx^n$ with $c_1+c_2 e^{3t}$? $x^n$ is a polynomial but $e^{3t}$ is transcendental!

Comment: @Math-Learner I updated the answer. Conversely, it's impossible for a polynomial to satisfy the recursive relation because different powers of $x$ are independent. While it can be shown that exponential expressions and constants do satisfy the statement, and thus so do their linear combinations.